# How to update the maven version without pom backup files

Tags: maven, versions-maven-plugin

How do you run maven with the versions plugin to update the version inside several pom.xml files and not get the annoying `pom.xml.versionsBackup` files?  (I have my poms in version control, so I don't need a backup).

I run this command to update the version:

`mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=3.8.0-SNAPSHOT`

Comment: adding .versionsBackup to .gitignore is also useful

Answer (score 111, accepted):

To prevent creating backup files, use `generateBackupPoms` instead:

`mvn versions:set -DgenerateBackupPoms=false -DnewVersion=3.9.0-SNAPSHOT`

I also saw that you can set up **generateBackupPoms** in the plugin section of a pom.xml if you want to do it that way.

Note if you are using eclipse, you can run the command using a run configuration like this:

[image]

See also: http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html

Comment: That helped, but a tip: with `-DnewVersion=${string_prompt}` eclipse presents a dialog for you to enter the version number, so you don't need to update your run configuration all the time (I also put the -D parameters to the Parameters further down, without the `-D` there). I think its much more convenient.

Comment: only problem: if you hit cancel that prompt (escape), it still runs and does useless bogus. Would like to have a way to catch that cancel, but failed to find one. If anyone knows, please respond here.

Comment: Awesome, would be nice to know if we can do this in Intellij too. I'll start searching.

Comment: Its not working on my jenkins machine. I am using -DgenerateBackupPoms=false but still backup poms are created. 
This is my command ->
 ```mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set \
    -DnewVersion=\\\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\\\${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.\\\${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}-SNAPSHOT -DprocessAllModules    -DgenerateBackupPoms=false```

Comment: In Eclipse, the `newVersion=${string_prompt}` will only work if you add in the **Parameter** section below, but it works.

Answer (score 38):

After `mvn versions:set`, run the command `mvn versions:commit`.

All of the pom backups will be deleted.

Answer (score 8):

**`mvn versions:set -DgenerateBackupPoms=false`** deletes the backups and will also ask the new version to be set instead of passing the version in the command.

Answer (score 1):

```
mvn -B versions:set -DnewVersion=${APP_VERSION} -DgenerateBackupPoms=false
```